# Apply recursive chmod to files or folders only

Tags: command-line, find, chmod, recursive

I'd like to apply chmods to files and folders in one line,

Basically:

```
chmod 700 ./* -R # but only apply to folders
chmod 600 ./* -R # but only apply to files
```

Of course I searched google and read manpages.

So the question is, does the following have any drawbacks, risks or is this safe?

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 600 && find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 700
```

Comment: It's cool, safe. You can do it without piping to `xargs` with `find -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;` but I think that yours will be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another possibility which I discovered using ACLs: the uppercase X. Given the following structure (three directories, three files):

```
drw------- 1/
drw------- 2/
drw------- 3/
-rw------- 4
-rw------- 5
-rw------- 6
```

It is possible to set the execution but for directories only by using:

```
chmod u+X *
```

Which will result in :

```
drwx------ 1/
drwx------ 2/
drwx------ 3/
-rw------- 4
-rw------- 5
-rw------- 6
```

Compared to `find` and `xargs`, this has the advantage of requiring one command only, and therefore no pipe. For this reason, I would be inclined to say that this is faster.

In your example, you are basically using two commands in one line:

- The first searches files, prints their names and `xargs` does the rest.
- The second searches directories, same behaviour.

In each of these calls, you run three **commands**:

- Run **`find`** so that it prints out the names of the files you're interested in.
- Pass these names to **`xargs`** so it acts as a wrapper around **`chmod`** (which is, therefore, called only once).

It is also interesting to note that by using `&&`, you make sure the second command is executed only if the first one succeeds (yet, I don't see how `find` could fail in your case).

However, when using `find` only (`-exec`), the `chmod` command is called for **each file** matching the `find` criteria. If you have 200 files in your directory, `chmod` will be called 200 times, which is slower than calling `chmod` once, on 200 files. Of course, in the end, since `chmod` is a relatively quick and casual operation, you will not feel the difference on a reasonable number of files.

Finally, another detail about passing file names between programs: spaces. According to how each commands processes file names (using proper quotes or not), you may run into trouble while processing files with spaces in their names (since *This Super Picture.png* could quickly be processed as *This*, *Super* and *Picture.png*).

Comment: `X` can also apply to file which already had execute bit.

Comment: @John: run this:
`find . -type f -print0 | xargs --verbose -0 chmod 600`
You will know that `chmod` will be called only once.

Comment: @ScylddeFraud Indeed, this is why I called `xargs` a *wrapper*. However, I have doubts concerning the use of the `-exec` option, which was recommended in an earlier comment. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: @John you have edited the comment. When I was writing mine, there was no `-exec` in paragraph about executing `chmod` 200 times. Yes, `-exec chmod` will be slow so I noticed in first comment to Dan's post.
And to your last paragraph about spaces, commas and quotes.
The `-print0` and `-0` mode of `xargs` takes good care of them.

Comment: Logged in to upvote this answer, but also add a potentially useful extra: `+X` is only additive, so you can explicitly remove the execute bit on files at the same time as setting it on folders: `chmod -R u-x+X,go-rwx <target>` will give you 600/700 on all files/folders from `<target>` downwards.